# Javascript in Django child HTML template not working

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am tried incorporating [this onload Javascript effect](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUV7C/) but it's not working.

Here is my `example.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-2 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">

          <div id="div1" style="margin:0px;width:100px;background:#666;border:1px solid black;position:relative;" >Waka Waka</div>

          {% block extra_js %}
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#div1").effect("highlight", {}, 3000); //this will highlight on load
            $("#div1").click(function () {
            $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
              });
            });
         </script>
          {% endblock extra_js %}
      </div>
    </div>
    {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

And here is my `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- For accordions -->
    <script src=
      "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

        <script src=
      "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'css/highlight.min.css' %}">
    <link ref="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ajax-live-search/css/ajaxlivesearch.min.css' %}">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.0.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

    <script src="{% static 'ajax-live-search/js/ajaxlivesearch.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js'%}"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
      }

    .shadow{
           box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
       }
      .btn-danger {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #f00000;
        border-color: #dc281e;
      }

     .masthead {
              background:#3398E1;
              height: auto;
              padding-bottom: 3px;
              box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
              padding-top: 3px;
    }
     .ls_container{
       width:100%;
     }
     #search-container.results{
       background-color:#fff;
     }
     #search-results{
       display:none;
       opacity:0;
       top:50px;
       z-index:10;
     }
     #search-results.active{
       transition: all;
       display: block;
       opacity:1;
     }
    </style>



            {% block content %}
          <!-- Content Goes here -->
            {% endblock content %}


  </body>
</html>
```

The "Waka Waka" div is the element that I want to be highlighted when the page loads. I also tried putting the javascript and the css code in separate files in the static folder but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Can you check in the network tab that the jquery script is being loaded

Comment: @Akash Yes, it's loading. I see a line there saying `jquery.min.js` with a status of `200`.

Comment: I also tried moving the javascript block including the script tags to the base.html template, but still the same output.